# C - Passing dynamic allocated 3D Matrix to function

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

In my main function i create a dynamic 3D array and succesfull alocate it.

```
    int ***board = (int ***)malloc(counter * sizeof(int **));
    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){

        board[i] = (int **) malloc(dimension[i] * dimension[i] * sizeof(int));
    }
```

Then i wan to pass it to a function defined as:

```
void readPuzzle(int board[][MAX][MAX], int *dimension, int counter,const char *);
```

I pass it like this:

```
readPuzzle(board, dimension, counter, argv[1]);
```

But i keep getting this error, i searched for it but never could fix it!

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:22:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘readPuzzle’ from       incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
readPuzzle(board, dimension, counter, argv[1]);
         ^~~~~
In file included from main.c:4:0:
headers.h:7:6: note: expected ‘int (*)[100][100]’ but argument is of type     ‘int ***’
void readPuzzle(int board[][MAX][MAX], int *dimension, int counter, const char *);
```

Comment: pointers on 2D arrays are not pointers on pointers on pointers. Those are different types. Also read about three star programmers: http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: What i wanted it was an array of 2D arrays but after reading a little about 3 star programmers i magically came to realization that i have a better way to do things!! I just stepped up a bit! Thanks

Comment: Which part of the code is unmodifiable?  If the function interface is fixed, then you need to redo your memory allocation -- dramatically.  If the memory allocation in main is fixed (I think it needs fixing even as it stands, but that's somewhat tangential), then the function interface needs to be changed.  You can't reconcile the irreconcilable; something has to change.  (It isn't clear from your last comment whether you still need help with this.)

Answer (score 0):

If your 2D arrays have variable dimensions, you need `int ***`, but this prototype

```
void readPuzzle(int board[][MAX][MAX], int *dimension, int counter, const char *);
```

isn't compatible with `board` passed as `int ***` because it required an array of 2D arrays, not a triple pointer.

So fix it like that:

```
void readPuzzle(int ***board, int *dimension, int counter, const char *);
```

but you still need to keep track of the dimensions for each "slice".

The alternative, if the 2D arrays have fixed dimensions `MAX*MAX` is to allocate an array of 2D arrays like this:

```
int (*board)[MAX][MAX] = malloc(counter*sizeof(*board));
```

now you can pass `board` as `int board[][MAX][MAX]`. Of course, if not all data is used, you still need to keep track of max dimensions somewhere.